# How to make this iframe use all height?

Tags: php, css, iframe, height, max

I was wondering how i could make 'this' iframe/div (marked with a red border) use all the available height. The iframe is 160px from top, and i want it to go to the bottom. When i set height @ 100% it will fill everything, but when i make the webpage less tall, it will show the scroll-bar very late. This is because he is 160px from top... Does anybody know how to fix this?

php:

```
<div id="sidebar"  style="display: none;">
    <div class="sidebar p1"><a onclick="toggle_visibility('sidebar');"><i class="icon-arrow-left-3 fg-color-white"></i></a></div>
    <div class="sidebar p2">settings</div>
    <div class="sidebar p3">change theme color:</div>

    <iframe id="data" src="/test/coredata/sidebar/theme_data.php"/>

</div>
```

css:

```
#sidebar{ 
        width: 315px; height: 100%; 
        position: fixed; right: 0px;
        top: 0px; background: #004d5f;
}
#data{width:310px; height:300px; position:absolute; top: 160px; left: 0px; border:3px solid #FF0000;}
```

screen:
http://puu.sh/21vAz (in url due 10 rep...)

Comment: doesn't look something that should be in an iframe in the first place

Comment: Well how would you do it else? It need to scroll when you pull more data.

Comment: you can scroll a div, just set the overflow

Answer (score 0):

You have set height of your iframe to be 300px:
  #data{width:310px; height:300px;

You should set it to 100% if you want it to fill all the frame

Comment: Nope sorry, as i said; When i set height @ 100% it will fill everything, but when i make the webpage less tall, it will show the scroll-bar very late. This is because he is 160px from top...

Comment: There is a solution for that with css3 using flex-box, but it works only on IE10, so I would not recommend using it.

Comment: IE10, what is ie, just kidding. It needs to work on Chrome and Firefox, IE... well, its nice if it works on IE, but it's not my primary target.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
function calcularAltura()
{
  //Calcular a altura da página actual.
  var the_height=
    document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.
      document.body.scrollHeight;

  //Alterar a altura do iframe
  document.getElementById('the_iframe').height=
      the_height;
}
//-->
</script>

<iframe width="700" id="the_iframe" 
    onLoad="calcularAltura();" 
    src="/test/coredata/sidebar/theme_data.php"
    scrolling="NO"
    frameborder="0"
    height="1">
</iframe>
```

IT should work ;)